# Extjs access one view from another

Tags: javascript, extjs

In Extjs, I am trying to access some data set on one view, from another view. Both the views are rendered on the same page. I created a small app in [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home) that shows what I am trying to do. When you click on the second textbox, it should show data from the first textbox.

**I want to pull it up using its reference value**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Hello',
            reference: 'HelloPanel',
            width: 200,
            html: '<input type="text">',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Hello2',
            reference: 'fooGrid',
            width: 200,
            html: '<input type="text">',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    element: 'el', 
                    fn: function() {
                        alert('Show data from HelloPanel1');
                    }
                }
            }


        });

    }
});
```

Comment: If it's for a form consider you could use the record to update the value of the textbox. Out of the box it should bind the new value to the textbox. Or use a viewmodel, but I don't know which version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this. Just made some changes:
Since there is only View presented you need to define `referenceHolder`.

Below example is too trivial to show power of reference. For that you need to make `ViewController`. Bind presented view to controller with `controller` config. Then in controller you can do something like this `this.lookupReference('superAwesomeTextbox');`. And now you have hook to that component in controller. It should be noted that `referenceHolder` is not required for `ViewController`. Simple as it is.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {

        var panel1 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Hello',
            referenceHolder: true,
            reference: 'HelloPanel',
            width: 300,
            items:[{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'textbox',
                reference: 'superAwesomeTextbox'
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        var panel2 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Hello2',
            reference: 'fooGrid',
            referenceHolder: true,
            width: 300,
            items:[{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'textbox',
                reference: 'superAwesomeTextbox2',
                listeners: {
                    focus: function(comp){
                        var textbox = panel1.lookupReference('superAwesomeTextbox');
                        comp.setValue(textbox.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        });

    }
});
```